# Angular: Mock a Login with $auth

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

I'm trying to work out how to unit test my login controller with Karma/Jasmine/Mocha.

I basically want to test if a 200 comes back from the `$auth.login()` then the message saved should be equal to "successfully logged in",
otherwise if I receive a 401 then the message that comes back should be "error logging in".

**UPDATE**

This is where I'm at, at the moment.

**login.controller.js**

```
function loginCtrl($auth, $scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.login = function() {
        var credentials = { email: vm.email, password: vm.password };
        // Use Satellizer's $auth service to login
        $auth.login(credentials).then(function() {
          vm.message = "Successfully logged in!";
        }, function(error) {
          vm.message = "Error logging in!";
        }).then(function(responses) {
          $location.path('home');
        });
    };
}
```

**login.controller.spec.js**

```
describe('Login Controller', function() {
  var q, scope, ctrl, auth;

  beforeEach(module('app.login'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($q, $rootScope, $controller, $auth) {
    q = $q;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();    
    ctrl = $controller('loginCtrl', { $scope: scope, SessionService: sessionService, $auth: auth, $q: q });
    auth = $auth;
  }));

  it('should present a successfull message when logged in', function () {
    var defer = q.defer();
    sinon.stub(auth, 'login')
    .withArgs({ email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test_password' })
    .returns(defer.promise);

    ctrl.login();
    defer.resolve();
    scope.$apply();
    expect(ctrl.message).to.equal('Successfully logged in!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is your controller test, you'd probably need to `spyOn` your service (`$auth`) like so (in Jasmine) -

```
var defer = $q.defer();
spyOn('$auth', login).andReturn(defer.promise);
controller.email = 'test@test.com';
controller.password = 'test_password';

controller.login();
defer.resolve();
scope.$apply();

expect($auth.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test_password' });
expect(scope.message).toEqual("successfully logged in");
```

and for the failure case using `defer.reject()` and pretty much the same format for assertion.

In my opinion, you'd end up worrying about `http` related status-codes or responses only at the `service` level and not at the `controller` level.  There you'd use `$httpBackend` to mock the responses with their status-codes and the corresponding responses.

**EDIT**

In mocha, as per my research, you'd end up doing something like -

```
sinon.stub($auth, 'login')
.withArgs({ email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test_password' })
.returns(defer.promise);
```

to `stub` the method.  And the verification of the call as -

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce($auth.login);
```

Rest of it remains the same.  The assertion of the message will also change to `assert.equal` for mocha.

**EDIT**

Checkout this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9bLqh5zc/. It uses 'sinon' for the spy and 'chai' for assertion

Comment: Is this any different if I'm using Mocha? Still not sure I understand spying on my service.

Comment: I've not used mocha honestly.  The equivalent on the mocha side for a `spy` is another library called https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon that gives the same facility.  Basically, you are `stubbing` the call to return a promise rather than make the actual call.  And by doing a `defer.resolve`, the promise is resolved to whatever you need as a result.

Comment: @realph - checkout my updated answer and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Comment: Can you post the test you've written here so that it's easier to debug?

Comment: I've updated the original question with the controller and the test, to better describe where I'm up to with the current issue. Hope it's a bit more helpful now.

Comment: You have two `.then`s in your code (not test).  Is the finally `location.path('home')` to be executed always irrespective of success/failure? Then you should replace your second `.then` with `.finally`.

Comment: I believe the `then` I'm getting an error on is the first `then`. I don't believe changing the second `then` to `finally` will solve this issue.

Comment: Checkout this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9bLqh5zc/.  It uses 'sinon' for the spy and 'chai' for assertion.

Comment: @realph do accept my answer if its a valid one.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the Fiddle. Really helpful stuff.